# Timeout in Jenkins for Windows

Tags: session, jenkins, timeout

does anyone know how to modify the session timeout and session eviction in Jenkins for Windows? Jenkins starts as a service. 
I edited the file *jenkinsHome/war/WEB-INF/web.xml* adding the tag "session-timeout" as below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<session-config>
  <!-- four hours -->
  <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins v2.107.1 and later, updating session-timeout is not enough.

You should set the sessionEviction time, which is 30 minutes by default. Try to start your Jenkins with the following JVM OPTS:

```
JENKINS_OPTS="--sessionTimeout=240 --sessionEviction=240"
```

Reference: [Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51734?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)